# How to send push notification to android app via .net web service

Tags: android, .net, web-services, notifications, push-notification

I am working on an android app and I have a soap web service. when data is inserted to database via website, my application should send notification to app users. 
How can I handle this issue ?

Comment: read about Google Cloud Messaging

Comment: You cannot push via a web service. You can poll.